# How to retrieve data from database through ajax using asp.net and c#?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax

I am trying to get data from database when i click button. 
I have one dropdownlist,one textbox and one button. 
when i click button it should get input value from drop down list and return one value from database and put it into text box.

[output window image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWORz.png)

dropdown has account number.

this is my ajax code its inside of head tag

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        alert("Entering");
        $('#btnBalance').click(function(){
            var accountNo = $('#DropDownListFromWhichAccount').val();

            $.ajax({
                url:'BalanceService.asmx/getBalance',
                data:{acc:accountNo},
                method:'post',
                dataType: 'xml',

                success:function(data)
                {
                    console.log(data);
                    var jqueryXml=$(data);
                    $('#txtBalance').val(jqueryXml.find('balance').text())
                    //$('#txtBalance').val("ok")
                    alert(jqueryXml.find('balance').text());
                },
                error:function(err)
                {
                    alert(err);
                }
            })
        })
    });
</script>
```

html code:

```
<div class="row content-padding-top">
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <label for="DropDownListFromWhichAccount" class="content-label control-label">Debit (From)</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">                    
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListFromWhichAccount" runat="server" class="form-control text-box-border" >
            <asp:ListItem>Cash</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>                
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtBalance" runat="server" class="form-control text-box-border" placeholder="Balance" ></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-1">
        <asp:Button ID="btnBalance" type="button" runat="server" class="btn btn-default" Text="Check" />
    </div>
</div>
```

asmx file:

```
namespace NibrassProject
{
/// <summary>
/// Summary description for BalanceService
/// </summary>
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET     AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
 [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
 public class BalanceService : System.Web.Services.WebService
 {

    [WebMethod]
    public BalanceChecking getBalance(string accountNo)
    {
        BalanceChecking bc = new BalanceChecking();

        bc.balance=bc.checkBalance(accountNo);
        bc.balance = "faisal";
        return bc;
    }
}
```

}

BalanceChecking.cs file

```
namespace NibrassProject
{
    public class BalanceChecking
    {
        public string balance { get; set; }
        string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Nibrass_DBConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

    public string checkBalance(string acc)
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Balance FROM Account_Balance_tb WHERE Account_Card_Number=" + acc + " ORDER BY Id DESC";
            // cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Account_Number",accountNo);

            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (rd.Read())
            {
                balance = rd["Balance"].ToString();
                break;
            }
            rd.Close();
        }
        return balance;
    }
}
```

Error message:
uncaught exception: out of memory

Comment: It hurts to see that SQL injection is still an issue nowadays

Comment: Out of memory? :o Is your while loop in checkBalance ending? How much data is being sent to the client?

Comment: @MatiasCicero i know this will cause sql injection. I just want to that value from database

Comment: @Shilly  That will return only one value. I already run and checked asmx file. That will return only one value

Comment: Is your while loop completing? You probably have an infinite loop somewhere, since you run out of memory. What gives the memory error? The webpage?

Comment: Try adding event.preventDefault(); to the script. The asp page might render your button as a submit button, which can cause the script to submit twice.

Comment: @Shilly where i have to add `event.preventDefault();` this code in my coding, thanks

Comment: In the event handler obv. `$('#btnBalance').click(function( event ){var accountNo = $('#DropDownListFromWhichAccount').val(); event.preventDefault(); .... rest of code ...`